# Multimap insert key typeinfo with std::make_pair vs std::pair constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, std-pair, typeid

I would like to understand why the following code is valid using std::pair constructor :

Code:

```
 std::multimap< std::type_index, void * > mm;
 mm.insert(std::pair<std::type_index, void *>(typeid(int), 0));
```

And gives compiling error when using std::make_pair:

Error:

```
C2248 'type_info::type_info' cannot access private member declared in class 'type_info'
```

Code :

```
 std::multimap< std::type_index, void * > mm;
 mm.insert(std::make_pair(typeid(int), 0));
```

Any clues ? Thank you !

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `std::pair` or `std::make_pair`. `type_info` must have a public constructor.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but *why* are you having a mapping from a `type_info` to a `void*`? What is the purpose of the mapping? What is the use-case? What is the problem you are having? To me it smells of bad design.

Comment: Since you are using C++11, I think `mm.emplace(typeid(int), 0)` would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of the `typeid` is a `std::type_info` object, which has no constructors defined. As `make_pair` deduces the template arguments for its output pair from the parameters passed in, it deduces `std::pair<std::type_info, int>`. It then fails to create the required pair for the above reason.

Your other line creates the pair with explicit template parameters: `std::pair<std::type_index, void *>`. This time, you are creating an `std::type_index` object, which *does* have a constructor, which takes an `std::type_info` - exactly what you're giving it. So no problems.

Your `make_pair` line would compile if it was also given explicit template parameters:

```
mm.insert(std::make_pair<std::type_index, void *>(typeid(int), 0));
```